# Broadcast receiver works in emulator but not in phone

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver

i'm working on an app which when enabled will reject incoming calls with a predefined sms. my app works fine in emulator. i tested it with two emulators. when i call one from another, it works seamlessly by immediately declining the call and sending an sms to the incoming no. i even received the sms on the other emulator. i have a strange problem here.
when install my app in my mobile, it is not working. i tried with two mobiles which is with android(2.3.3 & 4.0.3) but still no luck.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.praveenkutti1990.ezmesseger"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >

    <activity
        android:name="com.praveenkutti1990.ezmesseger.Ezmessger"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.praveenkutti1990.ezmesseger.Receiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="false">
       <intent-filter android:priority="999">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

and my broadcastreceiver is

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s[]={"9000000000","15555215556","15555215554"};

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    incomingnumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

    try {

          TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
          context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
          Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
          m.setAccessible(true);
          com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  

          for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if(s[i].equals(incomingnumber)){

                      telephonyService.endCall();
  }
 }
```

i added an option to enable/disable receiver in my activity. my intention is to block only specific numbers with an sms. everything looks and works fine in emulator. but not in mobile. i can't find where i'm wrong?

Comment: does your handset support telephony?

Comment: it does support telephony. i have already made similar apps but had no problem with it. just to be sure, i have already tested it in another mobile(samsumg galaxy s duos) also but its not working.

Comment: When it fails on the device are there any errors outputted within the logcat

Comment: You are calling private, undocumented methods on the `TelephonyManager`. Each device manufacturer can (and often do) provide custom implementation of these internal classes. It is possible that the methods you are looking for or trying to call are either not present or are protected. Please make sure that you log any exceptions in your reflection-based access to undocumented APIs as that may give you some clues as to what is not working. You could also connect your device to a debugger and step through the code on the device.

Comment: it simply doesn't work. no errors. as David said, the manufactures don't want third party applications to use functions like rejecting a call. thank you.